# Hexadecimal data in SqlServer is implicitly converted to a bytearray in C#. How to keep data as it is?

Tags: c#, arrays, hex

This is how our data is kept in the DB:

[image]

I'm getting the DB table in a datatable and looping through. 
The same data is implicitly converted to a byte array. This is from debug session:

[image]

I want the data as is. I will write it to a file. Currently I can access to bytearray with `row.ItemArray[0]`. Its value is `{byte[70]}`. There's no way to use index on `row.ItemArray[0]`. `row.ItemArray[0][0]` does not give you `86`.
I don't need `86` anyway. If I write `row.ItemArray[0]` to a file, it looks `System.Byte[]`

Comment: Your data type is binary, SSMS just shows it in hex in the query result window.

Comment: Any way to convert binary array into hex string in C#?

Comment: Yes, but what are you trying to write to file? Because byte array is already what you need to write to file.

Comment: I want the data in a text file to look the same how ssms shows us, if possible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

Why are you converting binary data to a string.  It will never work.  Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.dat";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable datatable = new DataTable(); //just for testing, use your current table
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.Create);
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
            foreach (DataRow row in datatable.AsEnumerable())
            {
                writer.Write(row.Field<byte[]>(0));
            }
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: OP states (in comments) that he wants data in file to look exactly like in SSMS, so - as a hex string.

Comment: It is not a hex string!!! it start with 0x.........  The code I posted will not change data and will work with any data type.

Comment: I mean in SSMS display it looks like hex string (with "0x", but that doesn't matter) and OP wants it to look exactly the same in a TEXT file (despite it being byte array in database).

Comment: The title says "keep it as it is".  Changing from bytes to characters is not keeping it as is.